# Pandas: Count how often different letters appear in cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a colum in a pandas dataframe. Each cell contains letter codes seperated by commas such as:

````
``` ['a, b, c, d', 'a, d', 'a, b, c', 'b, f', 'a, b, d, j', 'b, c, d',
       'a, f', '?', 'a, b, d', 'a, c, d', 'a, j', 'b, c', 'b, g', 'a',
       'a, b, d, e', 'b', 'b, k', 'b, i', 'k', 'd, k', 'a, b. c',
       'a, b, j', 'a, b, g', 'a, b, d, l', 'a, c, g', 'a, b', 'a, d, g',
       'b, c, g', 'a, g', 'a, d, e', 'a, b, d ']```
````

What's a good way to count how often each letter appears in this column across all rows, no matter in what combination?

Expected output:

```
Letter  Count
?       1
g       6
e       2
a       20
…       …
```

If I use df.columnname.value_counts(), I just get the value_counts() of each combination.

Comment: They contain strings that consist of comma seperated letters such as `a, b, c, d`.  Not `"a", "b", "c", "d"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with splitted column by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), also added some data cleaning by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
s =  ['a, b, c, d', 'a, d', 'a, b, c', 'b, f', 'a, b, d, j', 'b, c, d',
       'a, f', '?', 'a, b, d', 'a, c, d', 'a, j', 'b, c', 'b, g', 'a',
       'a, b, d, e', 'b', 'b, k', 'b, i', 'k', 'd, k', 'a, b. c',
       'a, b, j', 'a, b, g', 'a, b, d, l', 'a, c, g', 'a, b', 'a, d, g',
       'b, c, g', 'a, g', 'a, d, e', 'a, b, d ']
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnname':s})


s = df.columnname.str.replace('\.',',').str.strip().str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
print (s)
a    20
b    19
d    12
c     8
g     6
k     3
j     3
f     2
e     2
l     1
i     1
?     1
Name: columnname, dtype: int64
```

For DataFrame use:

```
df1 = s.rename_axis('Letter').reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
   Letter  Count
0       a     20
1       b     19
2       d     12
3       c      8
4       g      6
5       k      3
6       j      3
7       f      2
8       e      2
9       l      1
10      i      1
11      ?      1
```

Or for old pandas versions use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
df.columnname.str.replace('\.',',').str.strip().str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: Only problem might be the value b. c, where it is counted as one value instead of b and c seperately, but it depends on the specifications of OP

Comment: concerning "b.c",: yes, I noticed that data is not cleaned up entirely

Comment: @journo - So `.` should be replace by `,` ?

Comment: @journo - added repalce and strip for remove traling spaces, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

One method that you can use is to get all the values, then flatten it into one list and count how many times each letter occurs.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> pd.DataFrame(['a, b, c, d', 'a, d', 'a, b, c', 'b, f', 'a, b, d, j', 'b, c, d',
       'a, f', '?', 'a, b, d', 'a, c, d', 'a, j', 'b, c', 'b, g', 'a',
       'a, b, d, e', 'b', 'b, k', 'b, i', 'k', 'd, k', 'a, b. c',
       'a, b, j', 'a, b, g', 'a, b, d, l', 'a, c, g', 'a, b', 'a, d, g',
       'b, c, g', 'a, g', 'a, d, e', 'a, b, d '])
>>> list = df[0].values
>>> flat_list = [item for sublist in list for item in sublist if item != ',' and item != ' ']
>>> counts = Counter(flat_list)
>>> counts
Counter({'a': 20, 'b': 19, 'd': 12, 'c': 8, 'g': 6, 'j': 3, 'k': 3, 'f': 2, 'e': 2, '?': 1, 'i': 1, '.': 1, 'l': 1})
```